# Image Upload Not Working, Receiving No Errors

Tags: php

Here's my HTML form:

```
<form class="plist" action="build/build.php" method="_POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Package Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="packageName">
<br />
<br />
<label>Package Description: </label>
<textarea rows="4" cols="20" type="text" name="packageDescription"></textarea>
<br />
<br />
<label>Website: </label>
<input type="text" name="packageWebsite">
<br />
<br />
<label>Contact: </label>
<input type="text" name="packageContact">
<br />
<br />
<label>Price: </label>
<input type="text" name="packagePrice">
<br />
<br />
<label>Screenshots: </label>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
<input type="file" name="packageScreenshots" id="packageScreenshots">
<br />
<br />
<button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Build</button>
</form>
```

and `build.php`:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_FILES['packageScreenshots']['error'] == 'UPLOAD_ERR_OK'){
    $uploaddir = '/zips/uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['packageScreenshots']['name']);
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($_FILES['packageScreenshots']['tmp_name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['packageScreenshots']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "File was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Hmm...";
    }
};

// Create the zipped folder using ZipArchive()
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$full = $zip->open("/zips/$packageName.zip", ZipArchive::CREATE);

$zip->addFile('/zips/uploads/install.plist', 'install.plist');
$zip->addFile('/zips/uploads/google.png', 'google.png');

$zip->close();
```

The ZipArchive() function works great, there's stuff above what I showed in `build.php` where `install.plist` is created, that works fine, the .plist is created under the correct directory and compiled into the zip. When selecting and image for upload, the image isn't found under `/zips/uploads/` like it should be. Haven't been able to get it to work on either localhost or on my server. Tried PHP 5.4 through 7.1 (GoDaddy), with the zip library enabled. The directories have correct permissions as well.

Comment: Your html form method is `_POST` or `POST`

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov Correct. Should it not be that?

Comment: As long as I know there is `POST` method not `_POST`!

Answer (score -1):

Try changing _POST to POST. :)